# Zurb's Foundation 6 Disable Forms

Tags: zurb-foundation

I do not want to the default forms styling in the Zurb Foundation css framework.

What's the easiest way to remove it from Foundation 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replaced the default Foundation library (for my webframework foundation-rails gem) with a custom one from http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation without forms included